# How to check user role without using current_user_can()

Tags: users, user-roles, capabilities

I am filtering the map_meta_cap() function, which is called from $user->has_cap (which is called from current_user_can()). I only want my filter to execute if the current user is an administrator, so I need a conditional in my filter that checks their role.

I can't use current_user_can(), because that invokes my filter, causing an infinite loop.

Is there a reliable way to check whether someone is an administrator without using current_user_can() ?

Comment: Might want to look at the `$current_user` global, remembering to add global scope when inside a function..

Comment: thanks. i have seen a few ways i could check the user role from that object, but wasn't sure how reliable they were... might use `in_array('administrator', $current_user->roles)` ?

Comment: As long as you perform that logic late enough(ie. on/after init) it should be fine.. :)

Comment: Have done, though i've re-examined my previous thoughts, see answer... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check the `$current_user` variable to determine the role.

I believe it should be realiable after init(maybe even on init) for a logged in user, a guest visitor obviously won't have any data associated with him or her yet(so it'll be empty/unset).

You can also call up `get_currentuserinfo()` to populate the `$current_user` var, but i've personally never found a need when calling `$current_user` after init(but i'm sure there may be cases when you need to call it, so it's linked below for reference).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

Comment: sweet, i will check if $current_user->roles is empty, and if so, use get_currentuserinfo(). Thanks again!